# Set Cursor Position in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Yes, it is simple.

I have a simple pixelsearch function (searching for a brown pixel on screen).
If it found that one it should move the mouse to that position and click on it.

That works great already with fullscreen capturing.
To make the whole process faster I want to capture the Form1 window only (I made it transparent before so I can set and change the window size to capture only the screen that I want).

If it found the Pixel it doesnt move the cursor to the pixel position but to some position on the left top screen. Thats because it only captured the x, y of the form1 instead of the whole screen and moving the mouse to 40, 25 on screen is no the same position as the position of 40, 25 in form1.

How do I move the Mouse to the Form1 Pixel Position.

```
  Dim xd3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 193, 105, 79)
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As UInteger = &H2
Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As UInteger = &H4

Private Sub FindPixels()

    found = False

    Using b As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
        Using g As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(b)
            Try
                g.CopyFromScreen(Me.Left, Me.Top, 0, 0, b.Size)
            Catch
            End Try

            For i = 0 To (b.Width - 1)
                For j = 0 To (b.Height - 1)
                    If b.GetPixel(i, j) = xd3 Then
                        SetCursorPos(i, j)
                        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                        found = True
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End Using

    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind im dumb. Fixed it by adding Me.Location.X and Me.Location.Y